# Select only digits in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to select only digits containing `td`s.

Input:

```
<table>
  <tr><td>Open   </td><td>Close   </td><td>Price   </td><td>Volume   </td></tr>
  <tr><td>-----</td><td>-----</td><td>-----</td><td>-----</td></tr>
  <tr><td>  3.350</td><td>  3.800</td><td>  3.500</td><td>  0</td></tr>
  <tr><td>  2.750</td><td>  3.400</td><td>  3.500</td><td>  3.500</td></tr>
  <tr><td>  3.550</td><td>  3.200</td><td>  3.500</td><td>  0</td></tr>
  <tr><td>  4.150</td><td>  3.500</td><td>  3.500</td><td>  3.500</td></tr>
</table>
```

Output should be:

```
<fieldSet name="NZXGainers" value="60"/>
```

or

```
<fieldSet name="NZXDecliners" value="58"/>
```

Tried code:

```
<xsl:template select="table">
  <xsl:variable name="open-price" select="tr/td[3][matches(.,'[^\s*\d+\s*$a-zA-Z-]')][text()[not(starts-with(.,'-'))]]"/>
  <xsl:variable name="last-price" select="tr/td[1][matches(.,'[^\s*\d+\s*$a-zA-Z-]')][text()[not(starts-with(.,'-'))]]"/>
  <xsl:variable name="diff-price" select="$open-price - $last-price"/>
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$diff-price gt 0">
        <fieldSet name="NZXGainers" value="60"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <fieldSet name="NZXDecliners" value="58"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

The error I am getting:

`XPTY0004: A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the first operand of '-'`

Logic:

- Calculation: Sum of all companies where `td[4]` ≠ 0, and `td[3]` - `td[1]` > 0 then output `<fieldSet name="NZXGainers" value="60"/>`
- Calculation: Sum of all companies where `td[4]` ≠ 0, and `td[3]` - `td[1]` < 0 then output `<fieldSet name="NZXDecliners" value="58"/>`

I am using XSLT 2.0

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your template you match as table and its containing multiple tr so in variable in `td[3]` values are coming as per occurance of all `tr`, you need to change your context `table/tr` or use `xsl:for-each tr` inside table template:

**table/tr context**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">


  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

      <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="table/tr">
        <xsl:variable name="open-price" select="td[3][matches(.,'[^\s*\d+\s*$a-zA-Z-]')][text()[not(starts-with(.,'-'))]]"/>
        <xsl:variable name="last-price" select="td[1][matches(.,'[^\s*\d+\s*$a-zA-Z-]')][text()[not(starts-with(.,'-'))]]"/>
        <xsl:variable name="diff-price" select="$open-price - $last-price"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$diff-price gt 0">
                <fieldSet name="NZXGainers" value="60"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <fieldSet name="NZXDecliners" value="58"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Link: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94AbWBj

**For-each**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">


  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

      <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="table">
        <xsl:for-each select="tr">
        <xsl:variable name="open-price" select="td[3][matches(.,'[^\s*\d+\s*$a-zA-Z-]')][text()[not(starts-with(.,'-'))]]"/>
        <xsl:variable name="last-price" select="td[1][matches(.,'[^\s*\d+\s*$a-zA-Z-]')][text()[not(starts-with(.,'-'))]]"/>
        <xsl:variable name="diff-price" select="$open-price - $last-price"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$diff-price gt 0">
                <fieldSet name="NZXGainers" value="60"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <fieldSet name="NZXDecliners" value="58"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94AbWBj/1

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code:

```
<xsl:variable name="open-price">
    <xsl:for-each select="tr/td[3][matches(.,'[^\s*\d+\s*$a-zA-Z-]')]">
    <xsl:value-of select=".[matches(.,'[^\s*\d+\s*$a-zA-Z-]')]"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="last-price">
    <xsl:for-each select="tr/td[1][matches(.,'[^\s*\d+\s*$a-zA-Z-]')]">
    <xsl:value-of select=".[matches(.,'[^\s*\d+\s*$a-zA-Z-]')]"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="diff-price">
    <xsl:value-of select="number(translate($open-price, ',', '.')) - number(translate($last-price, ',', '.'))"/>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$diff-price > 0">
        <tps:fieldSet name="NZXGainers" value="60"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <tps:fieldSet name="NZXDecliners" value="58"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```